# What is the best practice to authenticate an Azure AD registered app?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I am developing an application which is based on GCP (Specifically it runs on the Google Cloud Composer (a managed version of Airflow)). From there I would like to connect to the Microsoft Graph API of another organization. So I want the application to be running in the background and every x minutes retrieve new emails from the inbox of an external organization, then do some processing and based on that perform some actions in said mailbox through the Graph API.

I am trying to figure out the best practice on how to secure this connection. I believe I could use the client secret of the registered application and then store that in an azure keyvault. Now I am not sure how I should authenticate my registered app such that it can retrieve this client secret which in turn can be used to access the Graph API?

As you can probably tell I'm not quite sure whether this makes sense or what a better approach would be? Almost all the information I am finding is concerning managed identities, however if I understood correctly these can only be used when the application is running natively on Azure, which for me is not the case.

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: I assume that your flow of retrieving new email should look like this: your app gather the client secret of azure application stored in azure key vault, and with this secret you can generate access token for calling graph api to retrieve emails. Right? If so, I really think it's a good idea for security.

Comment: I post some of my test result below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand, you can refer to my sample code, pls note you need to add key vault access policy first. And you may refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net#authenticate-and-create-a-client) to know about the default azure credential.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test0430callingapi.Controllers
{
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<string> IndexAsync()
        {
            const string secretName = "clientsecret";
            var kvUri = "https://key_vault_name.vault.azure.net/";
            var a = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), a);

            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
            string secretVaule = secret.Value.Value;

            //azure ad client credential flow to generate access token
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("azure_ad_app_clientid")
                    .WithClientSecret(secretVaule)
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tanent_name.onmicrosoft.com"))
                    .Build();

            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            string accesstoken = result.AccessToken;
            // this token can be used to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/mailFolders/{id}/messages
            return accesstoken;
        }
    }
}
```

I used client credential flow here which don't need to make users sign in, and [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) support application permission. If you use an api which only supports delegated permission, it can't work. Here's the api calling response.

[image]